# Feature Vector Builder - What design pattern can be useful?

Tags: java, design-patterns

My problem looks very simply, but only at first sight (for me :P ).
I need to create a class which builds a feature vector. This feature vector represents a text. Features are like : Avarage word lenght, Number of sentences in hole text etc.

Some Features can be extracted during other features computation, thats why I've modified a Builder design pattern a little, and it looks like this:

I am creating a builder object:

```
FeatureVectorBuilder fvb = new FeatureVectorBuilder(String text/InputStream <- now it doesn't matter)
```

then I am specifing an order, its express which features I want to include

```
fvb.setLenghtWord(True) <- for fixed length features
fvb.setXXXFeature(32) <- for variable length features
```

next i am building this vector:

```
fvb.buildFeatureVector() <- this way computations are optimized;
```

and finally I have a FeatureVector to get.

```
fvb.getFeatureVector();
```

Everything looks ok, but... there is about 32 different features to set...
This way, pessimistic case need 32 functions invocations, also creating a function with 32 parameters looks stupid.

I am wondering if somebody was struggeling with such a problem and maybe there is better solution than "32 different methods" approach :)

Comment: create 8 functions, each with 4 parameters? :) sometimes work is work and it's unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

One of the points of the builder pattern is to avoid methods with a large number of parameters by replacing them with several methods in the builder. If you have 32 possible features, it looks normal to me to have 32 methods in the builder.

Another possibility is to design each feature as a class, and to add instances of those classes in your builder:

```
builder.addFeature(new LengthWordFeature(true))
       .addFeature(new XxxFeature(32));
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to encapsulate the features cleanly would be:

```
abstract class Feature
{
    String name;
    ...
}

class NumericFeature extends Feature
{
    int value;
}

class OtherFeatureType extends Feature
{
    ....
}

Feature[] features = new Feature[] {
    new NumericFeature("xxxFeature", 32),
    new OtherFeature("feature1", ...),
    ...
};

FeatureVectorBuilder fvb = new FeatureVectorBuilder(text, features);
```